How to convert iter.Seq2[int, E] to iter.Seq[E] in go 1.23
For instance slices.Backward has the signature
func Backward[Slice ~[]E, E any](s Slice) iter.Seq2[int, E]

when slices.Collect has the signature
func Collect[E any](seq iter.Seq[E]) []E

How can i use them together?
it := slices.Backward([]int{1, 2, 3})
// collect back `it` to a slice 
// slices.Collect(it) -> in call to slices.Collect, type iter.Seq2[int, int] of it does not match iter.Seq[E] (cannot infer E)


FWIW, my jub0bs/iterutil package provides a function named Right for doing this.

iter.Seq2 is an iterator which provides both keys (or indicies) and values. There's no builtin conversion to drop the keys (so we get an iter.Seq as a result), but it's pretty simple to create one:
func Values[K, V any](seq iter.Seq2[K, V]) iter.Seq[V] {
    return func(yield func(V) bool) {
        for _, v := range seq {
            if !yield(v) {
                return
            }
        }
    }
}

Testing it:
is := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}

seq2 := slices.Backward(is)

for i, v := range seq2 {
    fmt.Println(i, v)
}

seq := Values(seq2)

values := slices.Collect(seq)
fmt.Println(values)

for v := range seq {
    fmt.Println(v)
}

Output (try it on the Go Playground):
3 4
2 3
1 2
0 1
[4 3 2 1]
4
3
2
1


I cannot fault your implementation, but I feel a bit uneasy about the function's name: pairs coming from a Seq2 indeed do not necessarily have key-value semantics.
